# How can I get the code to embed a YouTube video from the HTMLusing Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

My aim is to make a file for the video searched for in the input All code bellow works however I cannot find how to search the html code or write it to a html file). The end goal is to have something like a YouTube discord bot working locally. I need to extract the code for embedding the video without manually right clicking on the video.
I will be very grateful to those who help :)

```
import bs4 as bs

import urllib.request

import os

basic = 'https://www.youtube.com/'

search = ''

x = str(input('Song name: '))

y = ''

i = 0

x = x.split(' ')

y = x[0]

for i in range(1,len(x)):

    y = y + '+' + str(x[i])


searchQ = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+y


sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(searchQ).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

nav = soup.nav

for url in soup.find_all('a'):
    z = (url.get('href'))
    i += 1
    if i > 10:
        if z[0] == '/' and z[1] == 'w':
            search = basic+z
            print(search)
            break
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(search).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
page = urllib.request.urlopen(search)
html = page.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

os.remove('my vid.html')
f = open('my vid.html','w')
#f.write(str(html))
f.close


path = r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\my vid.html'
os.startfile(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used selenium to approach this problem. And I also removed all the usage of the requests library.

What my code does is that it basically goes into any YouTube Video and copies the embed code and outputs the code to the screen, using selenium.

You can then later write the embed code to any file in the format you want. That is up to you.

Also note that I didn't touch anything related to searching the video or choosing the video.

Code:

```
import clipboard
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

basic = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
search = ''
x = str(input('Song name: '))
y = ''
i = 0
x = x.split(' ')
y = x[0]

for i in range(1,len(x)):
    y = y + '+' + str(x[i])

searchQ = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + y
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(searchQ)
driver.maximize_window()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
nav = soup.nav

for url in soup.find_all('a'):
    z = (url.get('href'))
    i += 1
    if i > 10:
        if z[0] == '/' and z[1] == 'w':
            search = basic+z
            print(search)
            break

driver.get(search)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
video = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#movie_player > div.html5-video-container > video')
actionChains.context_click(video).perform()
embed = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="null"]/div[3]/div[1]').click()
text = clipboard.paste()
print(text)
```

Input:

```
fire squad
```

Output:

```
Song name: fire squad
https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=-MGB_G_ZjMo
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-MGB_G_ZjMo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping however after installing the modules and running the code I get a massive error ending in selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Hi Luc, you will need to download the chromedriver.exe from this [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.32/chromedriver_win32.zip), then your wil just need to add the executable to your project directory.